# Filter JSON to contain only desired values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been working on this for a while now and I can't seem to figure it out.  I have a JSON that I am pulling in from a link, and I'm trying to create a filter so that only names that start with a certain keyword show up.

I've been trying to use `.parseJson` and also I've tried `str.includes()` but I can't seem to get either working right.

Here's a piece of what the JSON looks like:

```
[
{
    "max_percentile_90th": 42142.1,
    "daily_percentile_50th": 21334.5,
    "timerName": "Booklet:Landscape",
    "sparks": [
        26651,
        23801.2,
        20850.8,
        19157.4,
        21198.5,
    ],
},
{
    "max_percentile_90th": 59253.4,
    "daily_percentile_50th": 9040.5,
    "timerName": "Search:Blog",
    "sparks": [
        9248.1,
        13653,
        8277,
        9532.2,
        10912.4,
    ],
},
{
    "max_percentile_90th": 16707.9,
    "daily_percentile_50th": 3793,
    "timerName": "Search:Records:Download",
    "sparks": [
        6257.6,
        8269,
        9395.4,
        6211.4,
        9420.7,
    ],
},
{
    "max_percentile_90th": 6979.4,
    "daily_percentile_50th": 2821,
    "timerName": "Search:AfterEffects",
    "sparks": [
        3752.2,
        4522.8,
        6167.2,
        3847.9,
        4568.9,
    ],
},
{
    "max_percentile_90th": 5900.8,
    "daily_percentile_50th": 2323,
    "timerName": "Booklet:Geneologies",
    "sparks": [
        3359.2,
        3317.8,
        3113.5,
        2839,
        2675.6,
    ],
}
]
```

So as you can see, the timerName STARTS with "Booklet" (but had different things after it) on two of them and starts with "Search" on three of them.  The JSON is much longer, but this snippet will get my point across.  So I want to make a filter that will only show the ones that start with "Search" or only show the ones that start with "Booklet".  I need all the data associated with it though, because I'm making a table, so is it possible to make a new JSON based on that?  Or how should I go about this?

Here is a fiddle from what I've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/xjcfw7zf/

Any help is much appreciated!  Thank you!!

Comment: I edited your fiddle, and it works, http://jsfiddle.net/te5j2fft/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about iterating over the main array in your JSON object using a for loop, perfoming a comparison using [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) on the current iteration object's timerName property, and then putting that into a result array on match, only to finally return that array?

```
/**
 * @param {array}  json
 * @param {string} filter
 */
function itemsByTimerName(json, filter) {
    var filtered = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {
        // if 'timerName' begins with 'filter'
        if (json[i].timerName.substring(0, filter.length) === filter) {
            filtered.push(json[i]);
        }
    }

    return filtered;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Filter will iterate through each object and filter based on a condition. indexOf will tell if the given key is present in the string.

```
function search(data, key) {
  return data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.timerName.indexOf(key) == 0;
  });
}
```

```js
var jsonData = [{
  "max90th": 42142.1,
  "daily90th": 21334.5,
  "timerName": "Booklet:Landscape",
  "sparks": [
    26651,
    23801.2,
    20850.8,
    19157.4,
    21198.5,
  ],
}, {
  "max90th": 59253.4,
  "daily90th": 9040.5,
  "timerName": "Search:Blog",
  "sparks": [
    9248.1,
    13653,
    8277,
    9532.2,
    10912.4,
  ],
}, {
  "max90th": 16707.9,
  "daily90th": 3793,
  "timerName": "Search:Records:Download",
  "sparks": [
    6257.6,
    8269,
    9395.4,
    6211.4,
    9420.7,
  ],
}, {
  "max90th": 6979.4,
  "daily90th": 2821,
  "timerName": "Search:AfterEffects",
  "sparks": [
    3752.2,
    4522.8,
    6167.2,
    3847.9,
    4568.9,
  ],
}, {
  "max90th": 5900.8,
  "daily90th": 2323,
  "timerName": "Booklet:Geneologies",
  "sparks": [
    3359.2,
    3317.8,
    3113.5,
    2839,
    2675.6,
  ],
}];

function search(data, key) {
  return data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.timerName.indexOf(key) == 0;
  });
}

alert(search(jsonData, "Booklet").length);
alert(search(jsonData, "Search").length);
alert(search(jsonData, "Something").length);
```

Comment: Your answer will fail in case search is made on Booklet and the timerName is "Search.Booklet"

Comment: @nikhil: Good catch. Somehow didn't think about it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To filter objects that start with "Booklet" can be achieved by following

```
jsonData = jsonData.filter(function(obj){
   return (obj.timerName.indexOf("Booklet") == 0)
});
```

For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/xjcfw7zf/3/

**Note** - To be more generic, you can have a variable as well in place of "Booklet"

Answer (score 0):

Use a library such as lodash, to filter based on which ever key and value you are trying to find, in lodash you would want to use "pluck" for what you are after.  Lodash is a very useful library which enables you to do all sorts of things with JSON objects, and javascript in general.

https://lodash.com/docs#filter